# Users having many closed questions.

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, post-ban

I know whether an user asks few questions and these are highly downvoted, then the system will not allow him to post more questions (for a while?).

But what's going on if an user has many questions closed as off-topic?

Comment: AFAIK the precise criteria are not made public (to make it harder to work around them), but it seems plausible "closed" is taken into account but I do not know. Yet at least it is taken into account for the "positive question record" as mentioned in the "socratic" badge description, which may or may not be a clue. (AFAIK most such bans are temporary.) [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) should be the standard reference.

Comment: @quid The reference is somewhat outdated: it predates [rolling question limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460) that are now the first, and probably main, line of defense.   Anecdotally (from a conversation that I can't find now), a closed question is about as bad as a question scoring -1.

Comment: @404 thanks for the update. The "anecdotally" seems compatible with the analogy with "positive question record" where a closed q (with non-neg score) is as bad as a negative scored q.

Comment: @quid btw, other than the question limits, which is based on a window, the quality ban is permanent, as in if you can't submit good content.